# Compare two files using bash script not working

Tags: bash, git-bash

I was trying to compare two files to check the content of one file is in the other or not.
Below if the code snippet used,
file1 is just numbers and file2 has the details (including the id) for that id in one line.
But this snippet is not working, it always says 'not found'. I have read through a lot of SO posts to see what I'm doing wrong; tried adding '-Fxq' flags as well, but to no avail. If I do a manual `grep "id" file2.csv`, it works.
Any idea what is going on? Something like run time bash variable expansion required?

```
#!/bin/bash
input="file1.csv"
orders="file2.csv"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    if grep "$line" "$orders"; then
      echo "Found..."
    else
      echo "NOT FOUND"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Comment: I notice your input is a CSV - when you read a `line` are you getting just the ID, or the entire row of that CSV? do you have a minimal example of your file1.csv and file2.csv?

Comment: Standard shell debugging trick: put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to get an execution trace, and see what's actually happening (and how it differs from what you expect) as the script runs.

Comment: Please [edit] an xtrace log (created by `bash -x yourscript`, or a copy of your script with `set -x` at the top) into the question. I _strongly expect_ that your input files don't match what you think they do (maybe one has carriage returns and the other has UNIX newlines), but we can't tell for sure unless we see a debug trace, or you add input files with which we can repro ourselves.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy was spot on, file1 had `\r` at the end of every line, causing it to mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone looking for the solution, The problem was the line read has `\r` at the end. Once it was cleaned up, `grep` started matching lines.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
input="missing.txt"
orders="detailed.csv"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
    id="${line/$'\r'/}"
    if grep -q "$id" "$orders"; then
      echo "Found..."
    else
      echo "NOT FOUND"
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggsting try `gawk` script:

```
gawk '
   FNR==NR {file1[NR]=$0; next} # Read all lines file1.csv into array file1
   {print; foundit=match($0,file1[FNR])} # print current line from file2.csv, and test line match corresponding data from file1.csv
   foundit {print "found in line."; next} # when reading file2.csv and mathed. print the match and read next line.
   {print "unmatched. "file1[FNR]} # if got here lines not match. print it.
 ' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Notice the numbers from file1.csv could be matched as sub-strings in large numbers.

For example if line #1 in file1.csv is `11` and line #1 in file2.csv is `3115` it will match.

It easy to refine the match if you refine the `match()` function in 2nd line.